# Generate random UUIDv4 with Elm

Tags: random, uuid, elm

I'm trying to generate random UUID's v4 within a loop:

```
    randomUuid =
         -- TODO: find a way to generate random uuid for variableId

    updatedVariables =              
         group.variables |> List.map (\variable -> { variable | id = randomUuid })
```

I read the doc of [elm/random](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/random/latest/Random) and [elm/uuid](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/TSFoster/elm-uuid/latest/UUID) but could not find how to generate an UUID without using a seed.

The only thing I could do is:

```
newUuid : Random.Seed -> ( String, Random.Seed )
newUuid seed =
    seed
        |> Random.step UUID.generator
        |> Tuple.mapFirst UUID.toString
```

I see that elm/random as an `independentSeed` function but I cannot get it to generate a seed.

The node equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve with `randomUuid` is:

```js
const { uuid } = require('uuidv4');

const randomUuid = uuid();
```

I feel like I might be missing some important concept in Elm here but cannot figure that one on my own. Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generating random values is an effect and as such a pure language cannot just perform it.

However, there is a pure version of randomness, which is using random seeds. These have the property that every time you generate a value using the same seed, you get the same value - hence this is just a pure computation and is completely ok in a pure context.

Elm allows you to execute effects as `Cmd`, the thing you return from your `init` and `update` functions. So one option you have is to always return `Random.generate GotANewUUID UUID.generator` *before* you need it, then perform your computation when you handle the `GotANewUUID` msg.

The other option is to keep track of the random seed. You either start with a deterministic one with `Random.initialSeed` (probably not what you want with UUIDs, as they would be exactly the same on every run of your program), or in your `init` function you return `Random.generate GotNewSeed Random.independentSeed`. Then you store the seed in your model.
Every time you need to generate a new UUID, you use your `newUuid` function above, making sure to store the new seed.

Here's an example:

```
import Random
import UUID

type alias Thing = 
    { id : String
    -- , some other stuff
    }

type alias Model =
    { seed : Random.Seed
    , stuff : List Thing
    }

type Msg
    = GotNewSeed Random.Seed 
    | AddAThing Thing
    | AddABunchOfThings (List Thing)

init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init flags =
    ({ seed = Random.initialSeed 567876567 
    -- Let's start with a deterministic seed
    -- so you don't need to deal with Maybe Seed later
     , stuff = []
    }, Random.generate GotNewSeed Random.independentSeed
    )

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        GotNewSeed seed ->
            ({model | seed = seed}, Cmd.none)
    
        AddAThing thing ->
            let
                (newId, newSeed) = 
                     newUuid model.seed
            in
            ({ model | stuff = { thing | id = newId } :: model.stuff
             , seed = newSeed }
            , Cmd.none
            )

         AddABunchOfThings things ->
             let
                 (newStuff, newSeed) =
                      List.foldl (\thing (stuff, seed) ->
                          newUuid seed
                              |> Tuple.mapFirst (\id -> 
                                  { thing | id = id } :: stuff
                              )
                      ) (model.stuff, model.seed) things
              in
              ({model | stuff = newStuff, seed = newSeed}, Cmd.none)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I gained a better understanding of the functionnal programming thanks to your explaination. And using newUuid the `List.foldr` was the key to loop while generating new id's from the same seed.  Thanks!